# How to record videos from an iphone App

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know how to record videos from an iphone app without making it to close..

it would be greatly helpful, if any one provides the sample code...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can see the Apple note:
[How to capture video frames from the camera as images using AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1702.html)